# mysql to compare field and values in clean way

Tags: mysql

I want to compare mysql field by clearing all special characters with dynamic value coming from text input.

```
$value = 'some - test's text';

preg_replace('/,|-|\.|\(|\)|`|\'|\//i', ' ', $value);
```

I want to apply above rule to mysql field as well, how can i achieve that?

like below query,

```
SELECT id FROM TABLENAME WHERE title like "$value";
```

`"title"` and `"$value"` should be compared using above `regex`.

Comment: your value is in `$value` but where is your `field` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `REGEXP` operator can be used in MySQL for a regular expression comparison.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: can you please elobarate more, bit weak in regex.